Persistent Warning: Remote Host identification has changed
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!

Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host 

I've been consistently encountering SSH connection issues to my VPS servers, regardless of the provider. I initially experienced this problem with a GoDaddy server, and I assumed it was a provider-specific issue. However, I recently migrated to an OVH server, and the problem persists. I haven't made any unusual or complex configurations that should be causing this.
I initially received a "Host Key Mismatch" error. Following the instructions, I executed the ssh-keygen command (ssh-keygen -R host) to remove the old host key from known_hosts. However, after this, I started receiving a "Permission denied" message directly
$ ssh-keygen -f "/home/intigo/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "myIPAddress"
 # Host myIPAddress found: line 3
/home/intigo/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/intigo/.ssh/known_hosts.old


$ ssh ubuntu@myIPAddress
The authenticity of host 'myIPAddress (myIPAddress)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:OGITneuOeu4tSWJash7NeYXpZ4CIdsdqkJFMcK8LGXp3SOHI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
Warning: Permanently added 'myIPAddress' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
ubuntu@myIPAddress: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).



$ sudo su
root@ideapad:/home/intigo# sudo ssh root@myIPAddress

root@ideapad: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

